# I'm struggling finding everything I need to know to pick out a pot

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, high-voltage, potentiometer

I'm trying to make a color mixer with 3 potentiometers and a lightstrip. Each potentiometer will control a LED, one red, one green, and one blue. The voltage requirement for the strip is 5v I think, since at the input pins, one of them is labeled +5v –

The total voltage is 4.5 volts, since I am using 3 AA batteries (1.5 volts each), and the strip needs 0.5-2 amps of current. So using Ohm's Law and the max current, if I did it right, it should be 2.25 ohms (is it 2.25 k ohms? or just ohms, because I've seen a ton of pots that are something k ohms). How would I pick a potentiometer accordingly? What would be the best for this situation, since if the resistance is too high, it would make the jumps too big I read somewhere. And how do I know if the voltage is too much for the pot? Does the number of a pot (say 10k) mean max is 10k ohms, or min is 10k ohms, or something completely different? If you have any other helpful tips related to this that I didn't ask about, please let me know.[image]

Picture of what my circuit design is. The grey wires are connected to diodes, so the current from the potentiometers don't go up them and make the current even, and then to the color pins, so when the button (3 pin, I used a switch in the diagram, but it is the same concept) is pressed the the current goes down the grey wires, and the current to the potentiometers is cut off, so the light turns white. When the power switch is turned on, the potentiometers should be able to change the color. For some reason though, when I turn it on, the light starts slightly red. (Found out why, it was because I had changed the pot value of the one that controls the red LED for experimentation)

Comment: why do you believe that you require a potentiometer?   ... you said nothing about the voltage requirement of the light strip ... you asked about picking a potentiometer, but you did not say what you would use it for, so that question cannot be answered

Comment: You need to actually tell us what you are trying to do. What may be obvious to you about your project will be absolutely unknown to us. Remember, we aren't mind readers and we know *nothing* about your project or what you have in front of you. This website has a schematic editor so you can put schematics into your post.

Comment: Are you planning to dim the light using Potentiometer? AAa batteries _cannot_ source current in Amps for long.. with three in series they will heat up and there will also be more losses in the batteries themselves. To present a good question, link the datasheet or the spec of the components you have... Wiring diagram of your circuit..and what you are trying to build

Comment: Why 3 pots?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Help us help you...

Comment: @DKnguyen Ok, thanks. And what do you mean project details? Do you mean the current and voltage requirements?

Comment: @EmeraldVolts I just meant more English stuff about what your project is. Namely the stuff you put into the comments. But I got tired of waiting and put it into your post for you. But yes, stuff like current and voltage requirements. Post a photo of your lighstrip and datasheet if there is one...the way you described it with a 5V requirement for the entire strip makes me think it is not dimmable.

Comment: @DKNguyen Sorry for making you wait. I was in school, and I had a test. And it is dimmable. On the remote for it, there is a dimming option. I tested all the options, and the dimming does work.

Comment: @EmeraldVolts It's more than just bare LEDs then. You need to give us enough information about it so we know how it is used for us to be able to help you out. Especially if it means intercepting the controller. It might not be reasonably doable.

Comment: @DKNguyen What do you mean "not reasonably doable"?

Comment: @EmeraldVolts To cut into it and fiddle with it since you say there is a remote. If you don't have enough knowledge to tell us what we need to know about how it works then we can't really help you in getting it to work. That's what I mean.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'm still not understanding. What do you mean cut and fiddle?

Comment: @EmeraldVolts Perform electronic surgery. It is less complicated to build something new than to go in and modify something to do that it was never meant to do.

Comment: @DK Do you mean to cut the sensor off? That shouldn't be a problem. My brother had one that stopped working for him, he couldn't figure out why (it was because it was disconnected from power, but we didn't know), so he gave it to me. It wasn't hard to disconnect the led from the pins that the sensor plugs into. Nevermind, I don't understand. How do you do this "Electronic surgery?"

Comment: @EmeraldVolts You can't just cut it off. You need to know what the wires are before you cut it off and what they do. I know nothing about this sensor so I'm just being general. It's possible it can't be done if you are unable to relay us the required information about how it works.

Comment: @DK I know, the pins are labeled. One is labeled R (Red), one G (Blue, they were swapped), one B (Green), and one +5V.

Comment: @DK I used my brother's old strip and did stuff with it. It can still be powered.

Comment: @DK I'll take a picture of my strip then, from the middle, so you can see the pins. I don't need the sensor, since I'm not using the remote.

Comment: @DK I'm struggling to take a good picture, it keeps coming up blurry. It has four pins. One Green, one red, one blue, and one +5V. The lightstrip current is 0.5-2A. The lightstrip comes with a sensor with a remote. The options on the remote are individual colors, fade, flash, brightness control, and strobe.

Comment: @DKNguyen I added a picture of the circuit.

Comment: sounds like common anode LEDs. circuit below should work except LED goes on top and resistors go on the bottom. you can look up what comon anode LED means. it just means they share a connection on on end so there are four pins instead of 6. wil update schematic later when at computer. you wil need to find a way t figue out forward voltage drop of each LED

Comment: @DKNguyen Yeah, the strip only has 4 pins, since they share the +5v connection.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ok, and what do you mean LED goes on top, and resistors go on the bottom? And I thought the circuit would work, but when I tested it on tinkercad with the button added, it makes the light go white when I turn on the switch, no matter how I turn the potentiometers. And when I remove it, it starts slightly red. And using the info in my question, do I need another resistor at the +5V pin? Do you have any ideas on how to find the voltage drop? Is that just how many volts each LED needs?

Comment: @EmeraldVolts See updated schematic. The LED sounds like it is common anode which means common pin on top and individual pins on the bottom. Therefore, anything that only affects the LEDs individually has to connect to the individual pins, ergo it all has to go on the cathode side (bottom).

Comment: @EmeraldVolts Before you even try building this circuit you need to learn how to light up just one LED. Look up LED and resistor and see how to size them. It is everywhere. Only then should you continue. Trying to make an LED circuit without knowing forward voltage drop is like driving without knowing what a brake is.

Comment: @DKNguyen I know. That's why I connected each potentiometer to an individual pin. And I connected a button to a battery, and connected a wire to the +5V pin, and the other to the blue and the green pin (cuz I was making something I wanted to be light blue), and it turned on when I pressed the button.

Comment: @DKNguyen So I figured out why it was turning white with the switch. Since 3 other wires were connected to each other, and to all the pads, the current was going to all of them. I just needed 3 diodes so the current doesn't go up the wires, just down. But now, when I press the button while the potentiometers are turned, nothing happens. Why is that?

Comment: @EmeraldVolts I don't follow what you are trying to say, or your drawing. But you can't share resistors or potentiometers between LEDs.

Comment: @DKNguyen I didn't say I was sharing resistors? What is it you don't understand?

Comment: @DKNguyen, I can't add a picture anymore. It's not working

Comment: Post a link and someone/me will edit it in for you. Also, _schematics_ is king here. There is a built in schematic editor here if you click on edit and the schematics symbol.

Comment: @DKNguyen What is the schematics symbol. And I think I got it in, but I can't see, since I'm on a  school device on school wifi.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'll have both there

Comment: @DKNguyen I said this to Simon B below, and I wanted to tell you too.

Comment: @DKNguyen So I found a bunch of different pots, the 10 ohm one was too expensive for my project ($2.50 each, and once again, I need 3), and I found a bunch of cheaper ones, things like 500 ohms, and 100, I prefer the 500 ohms one since it had a knob, and the others are trimpots, anyway. I saw this video where this person took a resistor and connected it to the outer pins of a pot to lower the resistance from 500K, to 300K. I don't understand how this works. Here is the video for reference. youtube.com/watch?v=W-TmOLPDLhc Does this even work?

Answer (score 0):

For an RGB colour mixer, you need something like the following, one for each colour LED.

R1 is sized according to the typical way that LED current limiting resistors are sized (you can look it up, it is everywhere and the absolute bare minimum you need to know to even attempt to light any LED), so that when R2 is set to zero ohms, the LED does not burn out. In this case, size R1 so that the LED current (and thus LED brightness) is the absolute maximum you want it to possibly be.

Do not assume the voltage drop for different coloured LEDs are the same. R1 needs to be sized separately for each colour.

You can size R2 however you want without risk, but it's probably best to pick something no larger than 5-10x that of R1 because when turned up to maximum resistance (i.e. dimmest) the LED will probably be too dim to see at any resistance higher than that so there is no point in needing to crank it up that high. Sizing it too will just mean the LED won't be able to get as dim as you would like. Sizing it too large will just means that the LED will turn off too quickly for too small a turn of the pot knob.

For example, just so you understand how to "get a feel" for how dim the LED will get:

if \$ R_2 = nR_1\$ then \$I_{min} = \frac {I_{max}}{n+1}\$

In english, that means that:

- if R2 is equal to R1, then your minimum current will be half your maximum current
- if R2 is double to R1, then your minimum current will be 1/3rd your maximum current
- if R2 is 5x to R1, then your minimum current will be 1/6th your maximum current
- if R2 is 10x to R1, then your minimum current will be 1/11th your maximum current

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGC5LG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To find the LED forward voltage drop of each LED, I suppose the easiest way is to hook make the circuit above, but with only one LED powered, no resistor, and use a very large potentiometer (1K or higher) and **start with it turned to maximum resistance** so that the LED is off.

Then *slowly* turn it down until you can see the LED just starts to light up and go no further lest you burn out the LED. Then measure the voltage across the LED. Do this for each LED then you can replace the 1K test potentiometer with more suitable ones.

Unfortunately in order to size the R1 and R2 as I described, you still have to guess (i.e. test your luck) or destructively test just what the maximum current is for the LED. If you're feeling lucky, you can keep turning the potentiometer down until the LED is as bright as you are willing to tolerate. If it has not burned out yet, measure the current (or measure voltage across the potentiometer, disconnect the potentiometer and measure its resistance and use I=V/R) and take that as your maximum current.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in your circuit design.  You have connected the red, green and blue LEDs all together at one terminal of your switch.  This means that you cannot control them individually.

The resistance of a potentiometer is just what its label suggests.  So a 10K pot has a resistance of 10K ohms.

You have worked out that you need a resistance of only a few ohms.  So none of the common carbon film potentiometers will work.  You would need a wirewound potentiometer, and you would need to check that it can handle the sort of current you require.  The smaller ones would overheat.

And AA batteries won't last very long at all at the sort of currents you require.

Comment: What's wrong with connecting them to one terminal on a switch? I need to power them all at the same time. It worked fine before I added the tactile switch, apart from starting slightly red. And doesn't a potentiometer change resistance? How do I check if it can handle the current I need? And about how long would AA batteries last?

Comment: Oh, did u meant the tactile switch? I figured that out, I needed 3 diodes.

Comment: @EmeraldVolts A pot has a fixed resistance end-to-end, and a sliding contact that connects some way along it, to produce the variable resistance.  Yes, diodes would fix the switch problem, though you will lose a small voltage in each diode.

Comment: Are there any pots with 0 resistance? How do I find the range of resistance, or max variable resistance. And still would fix the button problem. Is there a more efficient way for that?  And now when I press the button while the pots are being used, nothing happens.

Comment: @EmeraldVolts A pot with zero resistance is just a bit of wire.  It would be pointless - it would go from zero ohms at one end to zero ohms at the other.  Instead, the maximum resistance of a pot is the value printed on it.  The minimum is approximately zero.  A pot is just a resistor connected between the two outer terminals, and a middle terminal that connects to a slider that slides from one end of the resistor to the other, giving you a resistance between zero and the maximum.

Comment: @EmeraldVolts If you are using standard silicon diodes, they drop about 0.6V.  Schottky ones drop as little as 0.2V.  But as your power supply is already barely adequate for the job, a voltage drop in a diode may be enough to stop it working entirely.

Comment: I already know how a pot works, which is why I now see why zero wouldn't work. But I need a super low resistance pot. I need around zero because I need close to no resistance up to something around 2.25 ohms. What do you mean printed. Would I be able to see it in a listing online? Why would it stop working with a small voltage drop?

Comment: @EmeraldVolts (1) Low resistance pots do exist - search for wirewound ones as they can go down to ones of ohms.  Ordinary carbon ones are kilohms.  By "printed" I just meant the resistance value printed on the case of the pot when it was made.(2) Your LED strips are marked 5V.  Your battery box puts out 4.5V.  A silicon diode drops 0.6V, leaving you with only 3.9V to light the LEDs.  They will never glow brightly at that voltage.  But if they require up to 2A, they are never going to work well on AA batteries anyway.

Comment: I hooked one up to 3 AA batteries, even 2, it still lights up fine. I think 3 might be better. Would the pots drop any volts?

Comment: What happens if I go over the voltage requirement?

Comment: I can't seem to find cheap low resistance potentiometers.

Comment: And actually, I think the batteries I will use will be 1.2V each, since they are rechargeable. I will use four, so that would make it 4.8V, which makes some room for a bit of voltage loss. Either way, The diodes or only for a second of flash or something.

Comment: @EmeraldVolts "I hooked one up to 3 AA batteries, even 2, it still lights up fine. I think 3 might be better. Would the pots drop any volts?"  Yes.  If they didn't, then the wouldn't dim the LEDs.

Comment: @EmeraldVolts "What happens if I go over the voltage requirement?" You would shorten the life of the LEDs.  They may last for several hours, or just go pop, depending on how much you overload them.

Comment: @EmeraldVolts "I can't seem to find cheap low resistance potentiometers."  That's why nobody uses potentiometers to dim LEDs.  They use microcontrollers and pulse width modulation (PWM).  The fancy ones even have remote controls.

Comment: What are microcontrollers and pulse width modulation?

Comment: @EmeraldVolts A microcontroller is just a very small computer on a chip for running simple programs.  Almost everything electronic has one these days.  They are so cheap when bought in bulk that it's easier to use one than to design a custom circuit.  The Arduino board is popular for hobbyists.  PWM is turning the output off and on very quickly - faster than the eye can see.  It is more efficient than actually dimming the light, and looks the same to a human.

Comment: But I can't program or code. None of that solves the pot problem.

Comment: So I found a bunch of different pots, the 10 ohm one was too expensive for my project ($2.50 each, and once again, I need 3), and I found a bunch of cheaper ones, things like 500 ohms, and 100, I prefer the 500 ohms one since it had a knob, and the others are trimpots, anyway. I saw this video where this person took a resistor and connected it to the outer pins of a pot to lower the resistance from 500K, to 300K. I don't understand how this works. Here is the video for reference. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-TmOLPDLhc Does this even work?